# Adding x-ref to an element results in Uncaught TypeError: root is undefined on page load

Tags: alpine.js

When adding `x-ref` like this to a `div` and loading the page, I get an `Uncaught TypeError: root is undefined`.

```html
<div x-ref="commandview">
```

Alpine version 3.13.5.

That's the line in question:

```js
// packages/alpinejs/src/directives/x-ref.js
  function handler3() {
  }
  handler3.inline = (el, { expression }, { cleanup: cleanup2 }) => {
    let root = closestRoot(el);
    if (!root._x_refs) // error happens here
      root._x_refs = {};
    root._x_refs[expression] = el;
    cleanup2(() => delete root._x_refs[expression]);
  };
  directive("ref", handler3);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found this issue [comment](https://github.com/alpinejs/alpine/discussions/3003#discussioncomment-3424075) on GitHub:

> ...
> It seems like Alpine assumes that if x-ref is used then an x-data must be in a parent element.
> ...

By adding `x-data` like this to an parent element of the `div` I got it to work as expected:

```html
<div x-data>
  <div x-ref="commandview"></div>
</div>
```